# Porque file upload no lee por segunda vez el mismo archivo

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con esta duda de antemano muchas gracias.

En mi aplicación tengo un fileupoad de html para abrir archivos específicamente de excel y guardarlos en una carpeta en mi proyecto. Una vez que abro este archivo de excel valido sus columnas con TryParse si alguna columna tiene un campo indebido me manda un mensaje que el archivo contiene errores.

El problema es cuando corrijo el archivo y lo vuelo abrir y este ya no entra en mi punto de interrupción.

¿Alguien sabe porque sucede esto?

Aquí coloco mi codigo:

```js
 $("#fuImportarArchivo").on('change', function() {
        var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
      
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('#fuImportarArchivo')[0].files[0]);


        $.ajax({
            url: '/scripts/GuardarExcel.ashx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(output, status, xhr, resultado) {
                // alert(result);
                if (status == "success") {
                    if (xhr.responseText !== "El archivo excel contiene datos incorrectos por favor corrigelo") {
                        

                        $("[id*=lblMensaje]").css("color", "#04B404");
                        $("[id*=lblMensaje]").text(xhr.responseText);
                       
                        console.log("Entro en if");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("[id*=lblMensaje]").css("color", "red");
                        $("[id*=lblMensaje]").text(xhr.responseText);
                        $("[id*=btnEnviar]").css("visibility", "visible");
                        $("[id*=btnEnviar]").attr("disabled",true);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    $("[id*=lblMensaje]").css("color", "red");
                    $("[id*=lblMensaje]").text(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log("Entro en else");
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                
                alert("Ha ocurrido un error");
            }
        });


    });
```

```html
 <div class="custom-file">
                  <input type="file" id="fuImportarArchivo" class="custom-file-input" accept=".xlsx" visible="true" />
                 <label id="btnImportarExcel" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" for="fuImportarArchivo" style="visibility:hidden">Importar Excel</label>                
                 </div>
```

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            //Fetch the Uploaded File.
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];


            //Set the File Name.
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower();

            if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                //Set the Folder Path.
                string folderPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + fileName);
                context.Session["folderPath"] = folderPath;

                //Save the File in Folder.
                postedFile.SaveAs(folderPath);                   


                bool result = true;
                foreach (DataRow validacion in columnas_validacion.Rows)
                {

                // Aqui realizo las validaciones

                }

                if (!result)
                {

                    context.Response.Write("El archivo excel contiene datos incorrectos por favor corrigelo");
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(folderPath))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(folderPath);
                    }

                }
                else
                {                        
                    context.Response.Write("Archivo evaluado correctamente");

                }



            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Write("Archivo con extension invalida");
            }

        }
    }


    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: En tu navegador borra todo el cache para esta pagina.

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate ya borre el cache y sigue sin funcionar solo me lee una vez el archivo.

Comment: tu evento es onchange asi que usa dos archivos para que tu valor cambie,

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate eso es lo que me di cuenta cuando subia un archivo con errores y uno correcto y manejar uno solo ya no lo leia. Pero entonces que evento puedo ocupar para que solo pruebe  con un archivo y me lo pueda seguir leyendo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sugiero que cuando tengas el success, resetees el valor del file input algo como $(this).val('') , asi cuando reingreses nuevamente el archivo se genera el onchange

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate gracias he colocado lo que me recomendaste y funciona muy bien.